# No sound through HDMI with an ATI Mobility

Tags: sound, ati, hdmi

Specs: Asus G73JH i7/720; ATI Mobility 5870

I have read through *a lot* of threads on getting HDMI sound to work and non of them have fixed my issue. Granted I am very new to Linux and know only the GUI aspect of what it does from finding similarities that Windows 7 has. I would like to become a Linux Power User and I figured this would be a good step to get started.

I was able to successfully install my graphics driver and it shows in use. I connect the HDMI to my HD TV and I get no sound. I don't care about auto switch for sound, that would be great but not necessary. I just want my sound to work through the HDMI.

What I have tried:

**Changed**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

> pact set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-surround
>   Failure: no such entity

**Sound Settings:**

Right-click **Sound** indicator → **Sound Settings** → **Output** Tab, and set

```
Digital Output (S/PDIF) Built in Audio
Speakers Built in Audio
```

I only get 2 settings. If I right-click the area below those 2 in the "**play sound through**" box, I get no "**show hidden devices**". I am also doing all this with the HDMI connected to eliminate any possibility for error.

Comment: Have you tried with the fglrx closed source driver?  Some cards that seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the binary driver from Ati to be able to get HDMI sound working properly:

- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

also [pavucontrol [image: Install pavucontrol]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) for sound preferences helps a lot also...

This was the only way I could get HDMI audio working properly and selecting the sources (Analogue or HDMI) for output for specific programs to work...

Answer (score 0):

hdmiaudio out may only properly work in kernel 3.6 and later (we're talking open source radeon driver). 12.10 is only up to 3.5? So closed source or else learn to upgrade your kernel (you'll learn a lot but it will take you quite a number of hours to invest).

I know the radeon driver sources *say* that hdmi audio is working as of 3.5 but not as universally as you'd think that would mean.